# Logging errors in Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I’m trying to figure out logging, I want every time logging is called, where is it better to do this? to file? to the command line? I also do not have web.хml, how best to do it? here is the place in the code where I want to paste it

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        //do something like logging
        return "error404";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

I saw this on the Internet, I don’t understand how to connect

```
@RestController
@ Log4j2
public class LombokLoggingController {
  
     @RequestMapping ("/ lombok")
     public String index () {
         log.trace ("A TRACE Message");
         log.debug ("A DEBUG Message");
         log.info ("An INFO Message");
         log.warn ("A WARN Message");
         log.error ("An ERROR Message");
  
         return "Howdy! Check out the Logs to see the output ...";
     }
}
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi! Can you explain better what do you want? Do you want to know the best place to save the log information?

Comment: @Dherik i want to know, how can i logging my exception?maybe it’s enough to just add dependency to the maven? and then errors will be displayed in the console

Comment: When you start the application, did you see some error/warn message about `log4j` on the application log? Share the content of your pom.xml on your question too.

Comment: are you using spring boot? just add this dependency


`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
`

and make sure to install lombok in your IDE

Comment: @Dherik no, I didn’t see any errors, it’s just that I have to have logging in the project, i add pom.xmlin my ask

Comment: @RyanGuamos i have lombok in my project, i want, that my errors were recorded using logging to a file or in console

Comment: just add @Slf4j in your controller and use the logger
`log.error("this is an error")`

Comment: @RyanGuamos, okay, thank u so much

Comment: did it work????

Comment: @RyanGuamos, like yes

Comment: @RyanGuamos, as you helped Tanya, post your answer to Tanya upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just annotate your controller with  `@Slf4j` and use the logger.

`log.error("this is an error")`

Sl4j is just a facade for logging frameworks. Log4j2 does not work because Spring boot uses Logback as the default logger.

If you want to use Log4j2 instead of Logback. You need to exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging dependency  in the spring-boot-starter-web and add spring-boot-starter-log4j2.

You can use either `@Log4j2` or `@Slf4j` but I would recommend using `@Slf4j` so you wouldn’t have to change the annotation whenever you want to change your logging framework.

Comment: it is always good to explain your answer in a few lines like why you added Slf4j, not Log4j2 it would not only solve the problem and understand the issue also. I would then upvote.

Comment: Sl4j is just a facade for  logging frameworks. Log4j2 does not work because Spring boot uses Logback as the default logger

Comment: Edit your answer and describe there.

Comment: Although your answer works it would have been more correct to point to one of the many places that show how to configure a spring boot app to use Log4j2 since his question was how to make that code work.